# wireless connection issues as a server

Tags: wireless-networking, router, troubleshooting

I have a Belkin F9K1002 N300 Wireless N Router IEEE 802.11b/g/n router

I can connect via WiFi and Ethernet.

I have a few devices connected to it (cellphones, Raspberry Pi, computers, printer).

My problem is that when a local (LAN) server (ftp, http, ssh) is on WiFi, connection is spotty (more off than on). If the (LAN) server is on Ethernet, I have no problem.

I don't have any issues for the client on the WiFi (I can browse the Internet, download large multi-gig files, etc. fine)

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Oh, both the client and server are located right next to each other (and both are moved around), so it's not a reception issue